# OdbcConnection.ConnectionTimeout doesn't override DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

Using C#.NET 4.5.

I created an OdbcConnection (using NewConnection()) and set its ConnectionTimeout to m_timeout. Then I noticed when I access DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout, the value is still 15 instead of m_timeout. If I do (connection as OdbcConnection).ConnectionTimeout, then I do get m_timeout as the value. Shouldn't the OdbcConnection.ConnectionTimeout property override the DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout property? Am I doing things not properly?

```
    public IDbConnection NewConnection(ConnectionType type)
    {
        var connection = NewPhysicalConnection(); // connection.ConnectionTimeout is 15 here
        return new DBConnection(connection, type, NewExceptionTranslator(), m_timeout);
    }

    public IDbConnection NewPhysicalConnection()
    {
        var connection = new OdbcConnection(m_connectionString);
        connection.ConnectionTimeout = m_timeout;
        return connection; // connection.ConnectionTimeout is m_timeout here
    }
```

Edit: To clarify, this is done in a single thread.

Comment: Test adding the timeoout attribute in connection string.

Comment: I can, but I find that polymorphic property not working as intended to be a curiosity I would like to understand.